# how to save preprocessed image in kaggle output directory?

Tags: python, opencv, directory, kaggle

I want to save my preprocessed data in the kaggle output directory. The problem is, I want to save using the same name as the input file. so in my code, I have cropped and resized the image and now don't know how to save the cropped and resized images.
here is my code.

```
path ='../input/137x236'
train_data_path = os.path.join(path, '137x236')
images = os.listdir(train_data_path)
image_len = len(images)
images1 = images[1::1500]

h=64
w=64

x_train = np.zeros((len(images1), h, w,3), dtype=np.uint8)
index = 0
for x in images1:
 path = os.path.join(train_data_path, x)
 image = imread(path)
 image = crop_image(image, tol=82)


 image = resize(image, (h, w,3), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
 #image.resize(64,64)
 x_train[index] = image
 index += 1
 filename = 'path'
 
 cv2.imwrite(path, x_train)
 
 
 
 #print(x_train.shape)
#x_train = x_train / 255
#x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
 imshow(x_train[5])
 #print(x_train.dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this :
!zip-folder --auto-root --outfile /kaggle/working/dataset.zip /kaggle/working/

Comment: Please use less noisy formatting (e.g. the one for code according to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) and add an explananation.